# Equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions, rational-functions

I have this equation/problem:
Find the value of A and B 
if 2/(x−5)(x+3) = A /(x−5)  + B/(x+3)

How can I solve/approach this?
Thank you for your advice.

Regards
Lisa

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Multiply both sides by $(x-5)(x+3)$

Comment: Also, just to clarify, is the "a" in front of the $2$ a typographical error?  and please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is about decomposing into partial fractions.

To start with we know the l.h.s is equal to the r.h.s, and therefore we can write the following
$$
\frac{A}{x-5} +\frac{B}{x+3} = \frac{A(x+3) + B(x-5)}{(x-5)(x+3)} =\frac{(A+B)x + (3A-5B)}{(x-5)(x+3)}
$$
which we can set to be
$$
\frac{(A+B)x + (3A-5B)}{(x-5)(x+3)} = \frac{2}{(x-5)(x+3)}
$$
now we can compare coefficients.

First thing to notice, we don't have a dependency on $x$, this implies
$$
A + B = 0 \implies A = -B
$$
now we have
$$
2 = 3A - 5B = 3(-B) - 5B = -8B \implies B = -\frac{2}{8} = -\frac{1}{4}
$$
and finally
$$
A = \frac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac2{(x-5)(x+3)}=\dfrac A {x-5} + \dfrac B {x+3} \iff 2 = A(x+3)+B(x-5)=(A+B)x+(3A-5B).$

So set $0=A+B$ and $2=3A-5B.  $  Can you solve for $A$ and $B$ now?

Comment: Thank you so much.